# Making an unusual wrapper for python's sh

Tags: python, sh

I've been using the sh module for mainly executing Git commands. The problem I have is that sh spawns subshells to do the work and the std output doesn't get directed to the output of my main Python script. Of course, I can do the following, for each sh.git call, like as follows:

```
git = sh.git.bake(_cwd=repoPath)
print git.fetch().stdout
print git.log('-n=1', SHA).stdout
```

But I don't want to do that. I want to make a wrapper so I can embed the stdout print functionality in my git calls, so perhaps something like this but with the same results:

```
git = wrapper(sh.git.bake(_cwd=repoPath))
git.fetch()
git.log('-n=1', SHA)
```

I've read about Python's function decorators but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Why not call git directly not using sh? or use the [gitpython](https://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/intro.html) wrapper

Comment: But I'd still have the same problems for non-Git things, no?

Comment: Not if you do not use sh

Comment: Anything that spawns a subshell will give me the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
import functools

class wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    @staticmethod
    def _print_stdout_deco(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def print_stdout(*args, **kwargs):
            print func(*args, **kwargs).stdout
        return print_stdout

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        f = self._print_stdout_deco(getattr(self.obj, name))
        setattr(self, name, f)
        return f
```

This creates a wrapping object that delegates all attribute lookups to the object that is passed in.  When an attribute lookup occurs the attribute from the wrapped object is decorated to perform the printing to stdout and then returned.  Note that this assumes all attributes from the wrapped objects are functions, which I think is a valid assumption for the sh module but I'm not completely sure.  If this isn't the case you will want to inspect the result of `getattr(self.obj, name)` and only pass it to the decorator if it is a function.